# Android catch only Network related exceptions

Tags: android, kotlin, exception, retrofit, kotlin-coroutines

I currently have an app that is already used on Play Market but I have found an issue that I currently not sure how to solve.

The issue is that I don't receive ANR and Crash reports in Google Console. The reason for that is my Repository catches all exceptions, passes them to ViewModel and the localized message of that exception is then shown on screen.

The main idea of this behavior was to show user that in case network request fails, show the user that it was due to bad internet connection or server not responding.

However, what ended up happening is the fact that I am catching all exceptions and therefore all errors, even those that shouldn't be shown to users are shown in app instead of crashing it.

Please help me understand how I can limit my exception catching only to network related issues and all the other ones should crash the application.

Here is sample of the code:

```
suspend fun getUser() = try {
        withContext(IO) {
            if (!doesLoginInfoExist()) {
                HttpState.Failure(null)
            }
            val cookie = getCookie(userLoginInfoDao.getUserLoginInfo()!!.username, userLoginInfoDao.getUserLoginInfo()!!.password)
            val response = networkApi.getUserData(cookie)

            if (response.isSuccessful) {
                if (response.body()?.contains(LOG_IN_SUCCESS) == true) {
                    HttpState.Success(parseUser(response.body()!!, userLoginInfoDao.getUserLoginInfo()!!.password))
                } else {
                    HttpState.Failure(null)
                }
            } else {
                HttpState.UnknownError
            }
        }

    } catch (exception: Exception) {
        HttpState.NetworkError(exception)
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using Retrofit, I catch these exceptions for HTTP-requests.

1. [UnknownHostException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/UnknownHostException.html)
2. [SocketTimeoutException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/SocketTimeoutException.html)
3. [SSLHandshakeException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLHandshakeException.html)
4. [ConnectException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ConnectException.html)
5. [HttpException](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/HttpException.html)

The last one contains HTTP error code.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is exactly what I was looking for.